# How to mount nfs share from docker container?

Tags: mount, nfs, docker, centos-7

I can see the shares of the server:

```
[root@sandbox /]# showmount -e 192.168.0.111
Export list for 192.168.0.111:
/RAIDPOOL02/vers     *
/RAIDPOOL02/prod     *
/RAIDPOOL02/pipeline *
```

When I attempt to mount, I get this:

```
[root@sandbox /]# mkdir -p /192.168.0.111/pipeline
[root@sandbox /]# mount --verbose --options=nolock,exec,soft,intr,uid=500,rsize=65536,wsize=65536 192.168.0.111:/pipeline /192.168.0.111/pipeline

mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed May  4 08:16:49 2016
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nolock,soft,intr,uid=500,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,vers=4,addr=192.168.0.111,clientaddr=172.20.0.3'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Operation not permitted
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nolock,soft,intr,uid=500,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,addr=192.168.0.111'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.0.111 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.0.111 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 20048
mount.nfs: mount(2): Operation not permitted
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
```

I'm exposing these ports in my Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 2049
EXPOSE 20048
```

And I can successfully nmap port 2049 of the server:

```
[root@sandbox /]# nmap -p 2049 192.168.0.111

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-05-04 08:21 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.111
Host is up (0.00061s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2049/tcp open  nfs
```

Why am I getting "Operation not permitted"?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to run your containers in privileged mode:

`docker run --privileged=true`

If you can upgrade docker to 17.06, you can mount a NFS share directly, without extra capabilities:

`docker run --mount 'type=volume,src=src_name,volume-driver=local,dst=/mnt,volume-opt=type=nfs,volume-opt=device=:/nfs-share,"volume-opt=o=nfs-server,vers=4,hard,timeo=600,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,retrans=2"' -d -it --name mycontainer ubuntu`

Got the hint from the discussion here:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28809

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple missing parts.  NFS also requires port 111.

You excluded your "docker run" statement so I'm assuming you didn't have a -p switch for port 111.  If you're not redirecting ports, the port section of your "docker run" statement should look something like "-p 111:111 -p 2049:2049 -p 20048:20048" (without the quotes).